# How to narrow down the type from typeof T to T

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, typescript-generics

I have a function with the following signature.

```
 waitMessage<T extends IIPCMessagesConstructors>(wantedMessageType: T): Promise<// ?? //>
```

Where IIPCMessagesConstructurs are defined in the following way.

```
export type IIPCMessagesConstructors = typeof OSUserRegistrationMessage |
typeof AppLaunchRequestMessage |
typeof OSUserRegistrationResponseMessage |
typeof UserApplicationRegistrationMessage |
typeof UserApplicationRegistrationResponseMessage |
typeof AppLaunchResponseMessage |
typeof InstallationCompleteMessage |
typeof InstallationInitCompleteMessage |
typeof InstallationProgressMessage |
typeof InstallationStartMessage |
typeof InstallationStopMessage;
```

My function waitMessage returns an instance of the provided constructor. So how can I transform typeof T to T?

Comment: Use `InstanceType<Constructor>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InstanceType<IIPCMessagesConstructors>` done the trick